# AWS Cloudsearch email query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I've have an issue with CloudSearch'ing by email

For example, my search query is `host/search?predicate=aleks@email.com`

I have defined string `${predicate}* | ${predicate}` as my query and I've been trying to search in email fields. As a result I've been getting response only in case if I've been trying to query either part before "@" sign (`alex`) or full request (`alex@email.com`) all the time.

I've reserched [CloudSearch limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/limits.html), but I didn't figure it out finally: is it possible to pass Strings with "@" sign? Is there anybody who solved that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is predicate field `text` or `literal`?. It looks like it is text right now so cloudsearch stems the email thats why it will be stemed and stored as `aleks email com` thus `aleks` or `email` works when you search. You can make email field `literal` type so that cloudsearch doesn't stem in that case query will work for `ale*`, `alek*` so you can use `${predicate}* | ${predicate}`

Note: `literal` will be case sensitive search so u might have to downcase value before sending to cloudsearch if you want case insensitive search

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/text-processing.html
`@` is one of the characters that'll break a string part.  So you'll need to replace `@` with something else.
For english word breaking rules, you'll need to disable stemming.